# Parse delimited string with escape characters in a robust way

Tags: python, string, parsing

I imagine that this question is basic enough that an answer must already exist, but my google-fu skills must be lacking.

I need to parse strings with the following format: `upper:lower cc ; ! comment`. The character `%` is used to escape special characters `%:; !`. The `:` character delimits `upper` from `lower`. The `;` character terminates a line. The space character is used to delimit the `cc` element. Comments are introduced using `!`. The following strings should be parsed as shown:

```
a:b c ;        upper="a"   lower="b" cc="c" comment=""
a%::b c ;      upper="a:"  lower="b" cc="c" comment=""
a%%:b c ; ! x  upper="a%"  lower="b" cc="c" comment=" x"
a%!:b c ; ! x  upper="a!"  lower="b" cc="c" comment=" x"
a%%%::b c ;    upper="a%:" lower="b" cc="c" comment=""
```

What is the most pythonic (i.e. simple, readable, elegant) and robust way to approach this task in python? Are regular expressions suitable?

I tried writing a regular expression that used a negative lookbehind to detect an odd number of `%`s before the `:`, but apparently lookbehinds cannot be of variable length.

Comment: Is this some well-known file format?

Comment: @AKX it is `lexc`, for use with `xfst`-related tools.

Comment: There seems to be a Lexc parser here: https://github.com/Techievena/lexc2dix/blob/master/lexc2dix/lexc_parser.py ... but this seems suspect :) https://github.com/Techievena/lexc2dix/blob/master/lexc2dix/lexc_parser.py#L16

Comment: A starting point to parse upper can be `(%.|[^:])+`. The escaped characters in upper must then be processed in a second step. Further parts can be processed in a similar way.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think regexps can reliably capture the escaping state. Here's a state-machine style parser.

```py
def parse_line(s):
    fields = [""]
    in_escape = False
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if not in_escape:
            if c == "%":  # Start of escape
                in_escape = True
                continue
            if (len(fields) == 1 and c == ":") or (len(fields) == 2 and c == " "):  # Next field
                fields.append("")
                continue
            if c == ";":  # End-of-line
                break
        fields[-1] += c  # Regular or escaped character
        in_escape = False
    return (fields, s[i + 1:])



print(parse_line("a:b c ;"))
print(parse_line("a%::b c ;"))
print(parse_line("a%%:b c ; ! x"))
print(parse_line("a%!:b c ; ! x"))
print(parse_line("a%%%::b c defgh:!:heh;"))
print(parse_line("a%;"))
print(parse_line("a%;:b!unterminated-line"))
```

outputs

```
(['a', 'b', 'c '], '')
(['a:', 'b', 'c '], '')
(['a%', 'b', 'c '], ' ! x')
(['a!', 'b', 'c '], ' ! x')
(['a%:', 'b', 'c defgh:!:heh'], '')
(['a;'], '')
(['a;', 'b!unterminated-line'], '')
```

i.e. the retval is a 2-tuple of parsed fields, and the rest of the line after the `;` marker (which may or may not contain a comment).

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the answer from AKX, but I already had this ready when I saw it. Also, the approach is bit different (easier to adapt to a different format) and the result might be slightly cleaner, too.

```
def parse(line):
    parts = [""]
    delims = ":  ; !"
    escape = False
    for c in line:
        if escape:
            parts[-1] += c
            escape = False
        elif c == "%":
            escape = True
        elif c == delims[:1]:
            parts += [""]
            delims = delims[1:]
        else:
            parts[-1] += c
    return [p for p in parts if p] if ";" not in delims else None


lines = ["a:b c ;","a%::b c ;","a%%:b c ; ! x","a%!:b c ; ! x","a%%%::b c ;","a:b incomplete"]
for line in lines:
    print(line, "\t", parse(line))
```

Basically, this iterates the line character by character, keeps track of "escape mode", and checks the current char with the next expected delimiter.

Output:

```
a:b c ;        ['a', 'b', 'c']
a%::b c ;      ['a:', 'b', 'c']
a%%:b c ; ! x  ['a%', 'b', 'c', ' x']
a%!:b c ; ! x  ['a!', 'b', 'c', ' x']
a%%%::b c ;    ['a%:', 'b', 'c']
a:b incomplete None
```

Comment: The output is incorrect. `a%%:b` should be parsed as `a%` and `b`.

Comment: @reynoldsnlp Ah, yes, that did work before the last change. Fixed again.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment by @MichaelButscher, I wrote the following solution using regular expressions:

```
def parse_line(line):
    parsed = re.match(r'''( (?: %. | [^:] )+ )     # capture upper
                          (?: :                    # colon delimiter
                              ( (?: %. | [^ ] )+ ) # capture lower
                          )?                       # :lower is optional
                          \ +                      # space delimiter(s)
                          ( (?: %. | [^ ;] )+ )    # capture cont class
                          \ +;                     # space delimiter(s)
                          ( .* ) \s* $                 # capture comment''',
                      line, re.X)
    groups = parsed.groups(default='')
    groups = [re.sub('%(.)', r'\1', elem) for elem in groups]  # unescape
    return groups
```

This yields the following results:

```py
>>> print(parse_line("a:b c ;"))
['a', 'b', 'c', '']
>>> print(parse_line("a%::b c ;"))
['a:', 'b', 'c', '']
>>> print(parse_line("a%%:b c ; ! x"))
['a%', 'b', 'c', ' ! x']
>>> print(parse_line("a%!:b c ; ! x"))
['a!', 'b', 'c', ' ! x']
```

Malformed entries return `NoneType` object.